# Wordpress Thumbnail add action if no thumbnail

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I was learning how to make my own WordPress plugin, currently I'm confused on how if there is no thumbnail in the post then I use the default image as thumbnail. Code that I used:

```
add_action( 'the_post', 'mythumb' );

function mythum(){
   if (!has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $defaultthum = "http://example.com/default.jpg"
    echo ('<div class="featured-thumbnail"><img width="150" height="150" src="'.$defaultthum.'" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="7" title="" /></div>')
   }
}
```

**My problem:** The default image thumbnail is not in the right position. See [this image](http://s22.postimg.org/ezt05f59d/Lm_XUp.png) any idea? Or the hook `the_post` is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The hook the_post is not the right hook for this.

You can add a filter to the_content, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Answer (score 0):

For something as specific as inserting a thumbnail, I would declare a new hook.

```
/**
 * Register hook: thumbnail
 *
 * In the post, if no thumbnail exists
 * use a default instead
 */

function thumbnail_hook() {
    do_action('thumbnail_hook');
}
```

Then in your theme, you would add the hook:

```
<?php thumbnail_hook(); ?>
```

Finally, your action would then hook into that new space:

```
add_action( 'thumbnail_hook', 'mythumb' );
```

This solution allows you to place the thumbnail anywhere within the context of your theme's pages while taking something a bit closer to an MVC approach. In your case, you would want to add a bit more conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is sticking with the rules, the featured image is loaded using `get_the_post_thumbnail`. This function has a filter at the end, which you can use to see if there is a thumbnail. Like this:

```
add_filter ('get_the_post_thumbnail', 'wpse119033_default_thumb',10,5);

function wpse119033_default_thumb ($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
  if ('' == $html) {
    $defaultthum = "http://example.com/default.jpg";
    $html = '<div class="featured-thumbnail"><img width="150" height="150" src="'.$defaultthum.'" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="7" title="" /></div>';
    }
  return $html;
  }
```